# Can SMOTE deal with categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, unbalanced-classes

I am dealing with a highly unbalanced dataset to detect hacker intrusion in a network (~23k 0 or negative events, and ~1k 1 or positive events). I am using sklearn random forest algorithm. To deal with the unbalanced issue, I am using SMOTE based on [this code](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scikit-learn/5278). However, most of my variables are dummies. Given that the code requires the data go as a numpy array, they are coded not as factors or categories, but as integer. SMOTE thus creates the synthetic data with these dummy variables (originally coded 0/1) as floats. Is there any way around this? Otherwise, for a variable that would originally be, say, 1, I get 0.988 or 0.233. I thought about recoding these floats as 0/1 depending if they are < or > 0.5 but this doesn't seem the correct approach. Or is there a way to make a numpy array treat an integer as a factor?

Comment: What if you treat the float value as the probability $p$ that the feature takes the value 1 and then draw from a Bernoulli$(p)$ to impute the value?